# Write a new row with each column in python csv.writer

Tags: python, csv

I currently have a csv with the following columns:

```
id, width, height, item_id, design
```

I would like to append to this file and create a new row filling each one of those columns.  When I try it with let's say "test here" it places t, e, s, t etc in each row.
I would like to put data in id, width, height separte in example "new id", "new width", etc

My code so far is:

```
import csv

with open('design_products_view.csv') as design_file, open('templates_view.csv') as templates, open('templates_view.csv', 'a') as templatesToWrite:
    designs = list(csv.reader(design_file, delimiter=','))
    template_files = list(csv.reader(templates, delimiter=','))
    containsProduct = "Circle"
    writer = csv.writer(templatesToWrite)

    for row in designs:
        if containsProduct in row[1]:
            rowValue = row[1].split("'")[0]
            for row in template_files:
                if row[1] != "width":
                    if rowValue in row[1] and row[3] == "8":
                        print(row[1])
                        writer.writerow("test here")
```

writerrow only accepts one argument.  Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: `writer.writerow([id, width, height, item_id, design])`

Comment: see the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects)

Comment: ah man that's what I missed.  I was trying to do with out array, thank you!  @Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because `writerow` expects to receive an Iterable, like a `list`. Python treats `strings` as iterables of type `char`, so if you type `"hello"`, it will be processed as `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`.

Try using a `list` in the `writerow` function:

```
writer.writerow([5, 60, 55, 4, 'metallic'])
```